# MFC feature pack - Couldn't show the dockable pane once closed

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

By using the wizard, and selecting Office 2007 style, you can come up with a UI that looks like an IDE - a dockable file explorer pane on the left, and a dockable properties pane on the right.

However, when you close these dockable panes, there's no way you can show them again. Even if you recompile the project.

I searched through some forums and looks like I'm not the only one having this problem. Is there any way to show these panes again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings are stored in registry. I have created a project named "office2007", in the generated wizard file *office2007.cpp* there is a line which sets the settings path in registry: *SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));*

The path in registry where the settings for office2007 are stored is: *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Local AppWizard-Generated Applications\office2007*

If you want to have the initial state of the panes you should delete the registry key: *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Local AppWizard-Generated Applications\office2007\Workspace*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to delete your registry settings everytime, you can also add this line

```
m_bSaveState = FALSE;
```

to your CWinAppEx. It'll stop saving the state of your panes and reinitialize them every time the program opens.